# How to send data to AWS Sagemaker endpoint when there is a datetime field?

Tags: python, json, amazon-sagemaker

I trained a model in AWS SageMaker using AutoML. I have created an endpoint. Now I'm trying to send data to it, but I am having a problem sending it in the first format.

The training data has four inputs:

d_time: datetime

hour: category

day_of_week: category

shift: category

backup_calls: category

Hour, day_of_week, shift and backup_calls happen to be integers.

I have tried to send the data in the following way:

```
import boto3
import json
import datetime as dt

 
endpoint = 'endpoint-name'
 
runtime = boto3.Session().client('sagemaker-runtime')

data = {
    "d_time": "2023-05-19 03:34:34",
    "hour": 3,
    "day_of_week": 4,
    "shift": 3,
    "backup_call": 0
}

# Send CSV text via InvokeEndpoint API
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint, ContentType='application/json', Body=json.dumps(data))

# Unpack response
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
```

I get an error saying:

```
result = self._transform_fn(self._model, input_data, content_type, accept)
  File "/opt/ml/model/code/tabular_serve.py", line 60, in transform_fn
    raise Exception(f"{input_content_type} content type does not has correct format")
Exception: application/json content type does not has correct format
```

Can you please help me send the data in the right way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error states application/json is not supported can you test sending text/csv as the ContentType. You can then just send the payload as a CSV string with no column names. Use the order the model was trained with.

Comment: I tried, csv_text = '2023-05-19 03:34:34, 3, 4, 3, 0' and then 
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint, ContentType='text/csv', Body=csv_text)

I get the following error:
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1